# Link underline won't to go away

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for WordPress and when I add a link, the underline won't go away. The theme I'm using is *twentysixteen*. Here is my html:

```
<a class="thisisunique" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">some text</a>
```

I'm astounded that this doesn't work, since the `text-decoration` is even inlined. I also included this in my CSS:

```
a.thisisunique, a.thisisunique:link, a.thisisunique:visited, a.thisisunique:hover, a.thisisunique:active, a.thisisunique:focus {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

I even included code from a developer of the theme (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-underline-from-links-2/), who explained that the theme doesn't use `text-decoration`, but `border-bottom` to achieve underlines (for whatever reason):

```
.entry-content a, .entry-summary a, .page-content a, .comment-content a, .pingback, .comment-body > a, .textwidget a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

but alas, that confounded underline remained.

What's also odd is that when I do `text-decoration: overline;`, it actually adds the overline to the link.

What in the world am I missing?

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: You bring up an interesting point: while I was modifying the theme's to find out what was going on, I noticed nothing was changing. Turns out they were being cached, so I had to clear the cache each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tell you what you're missing!:

```
.entry-content a,
.entry-summary a,
.taxonomy-description a,
.logged-in-as a,
.comment-content a,
.pingback .comment-body > a,
.textwidget a,
.entry-footer a:hover,
.site-info a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor;
}
```

Where `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor;` is the son of a gun responsible for all this!

What the heck is a `box-shadow`? WHY???

This is what I found after digging through my entire WordPress directory for an hour. The code above is in the theme's *style.css* file. Anyways, just doing

```
box-shadow: none;
```

finally got rid of that darn underline.

Comment: `box-shadow` is sometimes used for underlining as it can give a different—and some argue nicer—look from the standard text-decoration. It's certainly more "styleable". [`border-bottom` and `text-shadow` can be used in similar ways](https://walterebert.com/blog/underlined-links-css3-box-shadow-text-shadow/).

Comment: Ah okay. I'm still pretty new to HTML and CSS so it's probably just me.

Answer (score 0):

try to make the styles more specific like:
    .widget-area .widget .link-style-1:visited {
    color: green;
    }
If possible share the location of the link..

```
    { parent. a.thisisunique, 
    parent. a.thisisunique:link, 
    parent. a.thisisunique:visited, 
    parent. a.thisisunique:hover, 
    parent. a.thisisunique:active, 
    parent. a.thisisunique:focus {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    }
```