# Wordpress Scrawl theme - can't get rid of hover line

Tags: css, wordpress

I've seen the other question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817351/link-underline-wont-to-go-away) but their solution did no work for me. When the mouse hovers over a hyperlink, a pesky red line appears underneath it. I've tried:

```
a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: none;
}

a {outline : none;}

.entry-content a {
border-bottom: none;
}
```

on Appearances->Customize->Additional CSS

on Appearances->Editor->style.css

also on the Slider Revolution Custom CSS because initially I thought this was an issue with the text in the slider, but later realized it's from the whole theme.

also on style.css:

- every instance of `border-bottom` was commented out and replaced by `border-bottom:none;`
- every instance of `a:hover` that had border-anything had that border commented out
- every instance of `box-shadow` was commented out and replaced by `box-shadow: none;`

The red line keeps showing up when I hover. I don't know what else to do. I also asked someone to clear their cache and cookies and then refresh the website. The underline/border/box is still there. Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: Impossible to determine the problem from this question.  Without knowing the full set of CSS being loaded, and potentially which link(s) have this issue, there's no way we can guess. Your best bet is to learn how to use your browser's console / developer tools, and inspect the link when you are hovering.  The console will show you exactly what styles are being applied, and where those styles can be found.  I recommend either Chrome or FireFox for their excellent developer tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: @cale_b is right -- use your browser tools to inspect the element, and also to change the styles dynamically to see if you can find the offending rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Scrawl theme preview, looks like it's an `::after` so you can override it with this:

```
.comment-content a:after, .entry-content a:after, .comment-respond a:after, .site-footer a:after {
    display:none;
}
```

Do keep in mind that for [accessibility reasons](http://webaim.org/blog/wcag-2-0-and-link-colors/) you should probably keep an underline of some sort, but this `:after` seems rather odd, not sure why they didn't just go with `text-decoration:underline` instead.

Comment: It was the ::after, and adding your solution to style.css didn't change it. However, adding it to Customize->Additional CSS finally worked. Thank you!

Comment: It's best practice not to edit style.css directly anyway. Any time you update the theme, any customizations you make there will be lost. Either Customizer CSS or a Child Theme ensures that your customizations stay in place.